# angular string from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a bit new to Angular, and I'm wondering how to create a variable – inside the controller – based on a position in an array.

I have declared the following variables without trouble:

```
$scope.chosenCategory = 1;
$scope.categoryNames = ["site", "country", "customer", "type"];
```

Then I try to do something like this, but it makes all the angular expressions in the controller's template stop working:

```
$scope.aspect = categoryNames[chosenCategory];
```

So, this is supposed to be a string showing "country" to begin with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$scope.aspect = $scope.categoryNames[chosenCategory];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is `$scope.categoryNames` instead of `categoryNames` and `chosenCategory` should be `$scope.chosenCategory`, so change it to

```
$scope.aspect = $scope.categoryNames[$scope.chosenCategory];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `$scope` to access controller variables

```
$scope.aspect = $scope.categoryNames[$scope.chosenCategory];
```

Comment: Thanks guys, worked. :) I'll click Accept on an answer soon, but there's a time limit.

To whomever downvoted, please don't do that, this is useful to beginners of angular you know, and there didn't seem to be a duplicate question.